# Warning: include(Mage/Core/Model/Domainpolicy.php)

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm getting blank product pages on my Magento website. When i check the system.log it gives the following error:

```
Warning: include(`Mage/Core/Model/Domainpolicy.php`) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

What to do?!

Answer (score 0):

That is because the file is missing. You need to download the version of Magento from https://magento.com/download and then add the file */app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Domainpolicy.php* to your Magento site.